# Links to references in mutt or vim

Tags: vim, mutt

Is there some automatic script that changes text with http:// links to references for mutt or a vim plugin ? 
Say I have

```
Text text, hey there goes a http://example.com link, 
hey the second one http://example2.com/. Btw have 
you seen the http://example.com ?
```

I want to automatically change it to:

```
Text text, hey there goes a [1] link, 
hey the second one [2]. Btw have 
you seen the [1] ? 

References

[1] http://example.com
[2] http://example2.com
```

Comment: Did you search the script section of vim.org? Did you try something?

Comment: Yes ofc I searched. I almost finished writing my own script for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's an interesting use case! As I already provide a set of general pattern extraction commands in my [ExtractMatches plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4795), as well as extended substitution commands in the [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602), I was able to leverage and combine the functionality of both.

My new [ExtractLinks plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4870) aims to provide just what you're asking for (and customizations for Markdown and HTML), in the hope that you (and others) find this useful.

```
This text references http://www.vim.org/ and http://w3.org/.
:ExtractLinks
This text references [1] and [2].
:put
[1] http://www.vim.org/
[2] http://w3.org/
```